# IonIcon Component to use Icons coming from "react-icons" package

Tags: reactjs, ionic-react, ionic6

I want to make **`IonIcon`** use react-icons like below.

[image]

```
Type 'IconType' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I understand the error, but is there a way i could still use react-icons.

Like this

[image]

Because i'm looping through some object, i'm picking some `icons` from `ion-icons` and `react-icons`, but `react-icons` has a type of `IconType` while `ion-icons` has a type of `string | undefined`. How do i merge these two icon libraries to use.

Comment: Do you want to use ion icon as a react component ? please check this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ionicons

Comment: I want to pass it to IonIcon component sir as a prop

Comment: Please check the question again, i have edited it

Comment: What is the definition of the type `IconType`?

Comment: That Type definition is coming from react-icons